# Should I create program shortcuts for all users or current user

Tags: windows, installation, shortcut

I'm creating an installer for my software (with NSIS) which creates shortcuts on the desktop and start menu. By default these are created in the current user area but I could change this to install in the all users area.

What is the correct thing to do? Is there a correct thing to do?

Comment: @Brandon Because sometimes people want that and if it's an acceptable thing to do then I can keep the install process simple. From your answer I guess it's not acceptable so adding an option is the best option!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user experience. Try asking at http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically agree with Brandon's comment although it depends on the environment.  If you're installing within an organisation and all users within the organisation (or department, or whatever) are likely to need access to your app then you can create the shortcuts for all users.  If you're creating an installer for public users then only create the shortcut for that person and provide the option for all users.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do that? That seems a little invasive to me. I would add an option if anything and ask for the admin's password.